# Use batch file to remove lines from csv with specific data in field

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have a batch file with 18 fields. Field 8 is an integer (1, 2, 3, etc). I want to remove any line where field 8 = 13. The code below is not returning the entire line; it returns the value !line! instead of the actual line in the csv file. How can I update this code to remove any line where field 8 equals 13?

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
1,MAY090178,D ,BATMAN HUSH COMPLETE TP,24.99,11.2455,11.25,13,7,         ,62464962,7.61941E+16,1401223176,9.7814E+17,                    ,0,DC COMICS,0
1,NOV141747,F ,BLACK BUTLER GN VOL 19,13,7.54,7.54,13,7,         ,62464962,,316259403,9.78032E+17,                    ,0,YEN PRESS,127143
2,MAY151682,F ,BLACK BUTLER GN VOL 20,13,7.54,15.08,13,7,         ,62464962,,316305014,9.78032E+17,                    ,0,YEN PRESS,127143
1,AUG180208,D ,BULLY WARS #2 CVR A CONLEY,3.99,1.7955,1.8,13,7,         ,62464962,7.09853E+16,,,                    ,0,IMAGE COMICS,140749
1,OCT180162,D ,BULLY WARS #4 CVR A CONLEY,3.99,1.7955,1.8,13,7,         ,62464962,7.09853E+16,,,                    ,0,IMAGE COMICS,140749
10,SUPPLY123,J ,COMICARE LONG COMIC BOX (SOLD IN 10) (NET),2.53,2.533,25.33,12,7,         ,62464962,6.0326E+11,,,                    ,0,,0
2,SEP180823,D ,FANTASTIC FOUR #4,3.99,1.8753,3.75,1,7,         ,62464962,7.59606E+16,,,                    ,0,MARVEL COMICS,140538
1,JUN160567,E ,FROM HELL HC,39.99,19.995,20,3,7,         ,62464962,,1603093974,9.7816E+17,                    ,0,IDW - TOP SHELF,0
2,APR162146,F ,FRUITS BASKET COLLECTORS ED TP VOL 01,20,11.6,23.2,3,7,         ,62464962,,316360163,9.78032E+17,                    ,0,YEN PRESS,136243
1,JUL110352,E ,GODZILLA KINGDOM OF MONSTERS TP VOL 01,17.99,8.995,9,3,7,         ,62464962,,1613770162,9.78161E+17,                    ,0,IDW PUBLISHING,129254
```

---

```
@echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem | Remove category 13 lines

rem SET "sourcedir=d:\data"
rem SET "destdir=d:\data"
rem SET "filename=%sourcedir%\file.csv"
rem SET "outfile=%destdir%\outputfile.csv"
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=," %%A in (file.csv) do (
    SET line=%%A
    SET string=%%H
    if NOT "string"=="13" >> file_13.csv echo(!line!
    endlocal  
)

@echo on
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"tokens=1,* delims=," %%A` tells the parser to split the string on commas, put the first token in `%%A`, and put everything else in `%%B`. If you want more variables, you have to specify how many tokens you are expecting. Also, once you split the string, there is no way to access the unsplit string, so you have to manually rebuild it.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=1-8,* delims=," %%A in (file.csv) do (
    set "string=%%H"
    if not "!string!"=="13" (
        >>file_13.csv echo %%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%F,%%G,%%H,%%I
    )
)
```

Comment: `if not "%%H"=="13"` - no need for a `string` variable (and so works even without delayed expansion)

Comment: I was trying to keep as close to the original code as I could